How to registerAsync a module in nest.js project
I'm not a very experienced programmer and I'm facing such a problem. I have a project built on nest.js and I need to integrate ConfigModule. I successfully updated initiating all modules so they use configService.get("ENV") instead of process.env.ENV but I can't do this with JwtModule.
This is my app.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        PORT: Joi.number().required(),
        MONGODB_URI: Joi.string().required(),
        MONGODB_DB_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
        ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
        CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
        CLOUDINARY_API_KEY: Joi.string().required(),
        CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    }),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: "30d" },
    }),
    DatabaseModule,
    UserModule,
    TaskModule,
    CategoryModule,
    AuthModule,
    ImageModule,
    NotificationModule,
    ConfirmationModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}`

I try to change JwtModule initialization with
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: configService.get("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"),
  }),
}),

but with this code other modules can't resolve dependancies for some reason:
[Nest] 1744  - 18.06.2024, 09:52:38   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, ConfigService, UserModel). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
  }) 

I tried to investigate but still can't figure it out.
